# SQL Use Variable to alter column length

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am exporting my data from a table T to CSV files, T has couple of varchar columns, at the time of processing, I don't know the length of data coming from data warehouse so I set the length to 500 (suppose), after exporting to csv file, I noticed that it put extra spaces after the data based on the length of the column.

What I want to do is alter the column length to is max data. So there is two questions.

1. Get the Max Length of the data inside a column in a table.
2. Use Variable to alter a column, the following code doesn't work stating "Incorrect syntax near '@l'."

   ```
   DECLARE @l int
   SET @l = 12

   ALTER TABLE Temp
   ALTER COLUMN a VarChar(@l)
   ```

Comment: a) It sounds like somewhere the data is being treated as `CHAR(x)` rather than `VARCHAR(x)`. `CHAR(x)` adds padding spaces to the end, as you've described. b) I wouldn't recommend altering the column lengths. Just use a suitably large `VARCHAR(x)` (e.g. `VARCHAR(500)` or `VARCHAR(MAX)`) and perform an `RTRIM()` at some appropriate stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, directly.

You *could* perform a bit of dynamic SQL:

```
create table Temp (a varchar(20) not null)

DECLARE @l int
SET @l = 12

declare @Sql nvarchar(max)
set @Sql = '
ALTER TABLE Temp
ALTER COLUMN a VarChar(' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@l) + ') not null'
exec sp_executesql @Sql
```

But, as I indicated in my comments, I wouldn't recommend this. I'd recommend a) finding out where the padding is being added, or b) Using a [`RTRIM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) at an appropriate place to remove the padding.

I'd leave the column definitions alone.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DECLARE @l int
SET @l = 12
DECLARE @strsql varchar(500)
SET @strsql='ALTER TABLE tbl4 ALTER COLUMN col1 VarChar('+cast(@l as varchar(5))+')'
exec(@strsql)
```